# TypeScript: Are argument types needed when implementing an interface?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Suppose I have the following interface `IFace`, and an implementation of the interface `Add`:

```
interface IFace {
    add(a: number, b:number): number
}

class Add implements IFace {
   add(a,b)
}
```

When implementing the `add()` method in my `Add` class, is it possible to do so without specifying:

1. the return type of the method?
2. the types of arguments `a` and `b`?

I tried searching on Stack Overflow and the ​internet didn't find anything relevant.

Comment: I'd say yes, as functions (and methods) can be type-overloaded in typescript. Therefore it is not quite clear wether `add(a, b)` does implement `IFace.add` or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of each argument must be specified in the method signature of your `Add` classes `add()` function, [as per the typescript syntax requirements](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html). The return type of your `Add` classes `add()` function can however be inferred from the interface being implemented, and need not be provided explicitly.

The following would therefore be valid:

```
interface IFace {
    add(a: number, b:number): number
}

class Add implements IFace {

 /* Must supply number types for a and b, but return type of function be be omitted */
 add(a:number,b:number) {
    return a + b;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as from the official typescrip doc (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) 
Interfaces describe the public side of the class, rather than both the public and private side. This prohibits you from using them to check that a class also has particular types for the private side of the class instance (so yes, you need to define the type of a & b, and d in this case)

```
interface ClockInterface {
    currentTime: Date;
    setTime(d: Date): void;
}

class Clock implements ClockInterface {
    currentTime: Date = new Date();
    setTime(d: Date) {
        this.currentTime = d;
    }
    constructor(h: number, m: number) { }
}
```